# How to avoid side effect in for loop using slicing operator in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, slice

This is quoted from the link : http://www.python-course.eu/for_loop.php -
*To avoid these side effects, it's best to work on a copy by using the slicing operator, as can be seen in the next example:*

```
colours = ["red"]
for i in colours[:]:
    if i == "red":
        colours += ["black"]
    if i == "black":
        colours += ["white"]
print colours
```

The output is :

```
['red', 'black']
```

My question is: does the statement `colours[:]` makes a copy of the colours list and the for loop works on the copy instead of the original list? If it is so, then how the `["balck"]` is appended to the original colour list?

Comment: Yes but you are still adding to the original list. Make a new copy before you loop and append to that.

Comment: you should have added the full code as it is completely different to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**does the statement `colours[:]` makes a copy of the colours list**: Yes.

**and the for loop works on the copy instead of the original list?** Yes, but be careful what you mean by "works on". The variable `i` takes its values from a copy of list `colours`. However, the references to `colours` such as in the line `colours += ["black"]` refer to the original list. That is just what the code wants, so it works.

**If it is so, then how the ["balck"] is appended to the original colour list?** This is because the line that does the appending refers to the original list and not the copy of the list.

Comment: so if I write `colours[:]+=["black"]` then it will append to the copy list, and there will be no any effect on the original list? And secondly, can a copy be altered?

Comment: If you would write `colours[:]+=["black"]`, you'd append to a new copy, not the one you're iterating over.

Comment: @dlpnrwbie96, no you need to create a new list, `new = colours[:]` and append to new

Comment: @dlpnewbie96: Yes, a new copy of the list would be altered, but since you do not save the result anywhere the alteration is lost and of no value. The copy that is altered would be different from the copy made in the line `for i in colours[:]:`--it is created, altered, and lost in the same line. So a copy can be altered, which has its advantages and disadvantages. The copy in the `for` line is stored and used for the length of the loop and is accessed only through variable `i` do to the `for` line. Is that clear?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I have changed the code to `colours[:]+=["black"]` but the output is again the same. How the "black" is appended to the original list then?

Comment: @dlpnewbie96: As I said, the string `"black"` is indeed appended to a list in  your new code, but it is appended *to the wrong list*. It is appended to a temporary copy which is quickly lost. To change the original list you must refer to it, not to a copy, and that is what happens in the code you posted in your question.

Answer (score 2):

`colours[:]` makes a copy of the original list and iterates over it, but `colours` remains the original list. The following code would be equivalent:

```
copy = colours.copy()
for i in copy:
    if i == "red":
        colours.append("black")  # append is O(1)
    if i == "black":
        colours.append("white")
```

Comment: Use append to add to the list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I just copied the original code verbatim, but yes, changed.

Comment: You still need to iterate over the original list to match the intention of the code

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you are referring to in the [link](http://www.python-course.eu/for_loop.php) provided:

*If you loop over a list, it's best to avoid changing the list in the loop body. To give you an example, what can happen, have a look at the following example:*

```
colours = ["red"]
for i in colours:
    if i == "red":
        colours += ["black"]
    if i == "black":
        colours += ["white"]
print colours
```

*What will be printed by "print colours"?*

```
['red', 'black', 'white']
```

*To avoid these side effects, it's best to work on a copy by using the slicing operator, as can be seen in the next example*:

```
colours = ["red"]
for i in colours[:]:
    if i == "red":
        colours += ["black"]
    if i == "black":
        colours += ["white"]
print colours
Now the output looks like this:
['red', 'black']
```

*We still might have done something, what we shouldn't have done. We changed the list "colours", but our change hasn't had any effect on the loop anymore. The elements to be looped remained the same during the iterations.*

So:

```
colours = ["red"]
for i in colours[:]: # iterates over a copy so we only evaluate what is in the list originally
    if i == "red":
        colours += ["black"]
    if i == "black":
        colours += ["white"]
print(colours) # ["red", "black"]
```

Now no copy:

```
colours = ["red"]
for i in colours:
    if i == "red":
        colours += ["black"] # black gets added, colours -> ["red", "black"]
    if i == "black": # now because of ^^, white gets added.
        colours += ["white"]
print(colours) # -> ['red', 'black', 'white']
```

Now an even worse case:

```
colours = ["red"]
for i in colours:
    if i == "red":
        colours += ["red"] # red gets add, colours = ["red", "red"]
                          # 2nd iteration, red gets added, colours ->  colours = ["red", "red", "red"]
                          # infinite loop....
    if i == "black":
        colours += ["white"]
print(colours)
```

What you are doing is completely different to what the example is trying to show, it is trying to avoid adding elements to the list you are iterating over so you only evaluate elements from the original list not newly added elements. You are trying to create a new list:

```
colours = ["red"]
new = colours[:] # assign new list/copy to a name.
for i in colours:
    if i == "red":
        new += ["red"] # add to new list
    if i == "black":
        new += ["white"]
print(colours)
```

You should also `append` not `+=`:

```
colours = ["red"]
new = colours[:]
for i in colours:
    if i == "red":
        new.append("red")
    if i == "black":
        new.append("white")
print(colours)
```